# Bootstrap carousel images don't always show; images restored ony after clearing cache

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, image, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel that is proving problematic. It works well - sometimes! Randomly, the images "break." The "broken image" icon shows and the alt text is displayed. The carousel still works in terms of advancing to the next image and the controls and indicators. However, in order to fix the broken image issue, I have to erase browser cache, content settings, etc. I don't want this to happen to users.

I would like the carousel to continuously work without having to clear browser cache and browser data content, etc.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When it breaks have you used the developer tools built into the browser to look at the page and see why it is broken? Does it break on an image it has shown correctly before during that page load? Does it break on the same image each time?

Comment: Hi Jason: it does not appearing to be any one image that is actually breaking the carousel but rather to do with the number of times it is viewed? I'm not sure this is making sense. I'll try to put in the code I used for the carousel (but was having trouble getting it to accept my code to post).